# UIWebView not causing document.ready to fire

Tags: jquery, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a simple application that does nothing more than load an `NSURLRequest` in a `UIWebView`.  If I load this either using the simulator or on a device, the jQuery method `$(document).ready` doesn't fire.  I have created a test page to verify this:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3660978/webviewtest.html

Here is the code that loads up the WebView:

```
-(void)loadWebView {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3660978/webviewtest.html"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

#pragma mark - WebView Delegate Method
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"WebView is done loading");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadWebView];
}
```

If I load this up using the Safari app on my iPad, it works fine (I get two alerts), whenever I run the app using either the simulator or that same iPad it fails to call `$(document).ready` (I only get the first alert).

I have tried using both iOS 5 and iOS 6.1 simulators.  What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you have for jQuery isn't complete.  In your dropbox it begins: `//` instead of `http://`, so jQuery doesn't load, hence the call for document.ready (which is in jQuery) doesn't run.

The alternative is to embed the jQuery library in the bundle and reference it locally.

Comment: Well duh!  Weird that it worked in the Safari app just fine though.  But you are right, fixing the pointer to the library fixed the issue.  Now to see if that same issue exists for my .NET application.  I found another SO post that indicated there were issues with .NET 4.0 not recognizing the web client properly.